# Get a QuerySet only linked to the particular slug

Tags: django

I want to display a QuerySet("link" parameter in below html) only linked to the particular slug.
However I am getting all QuerySets by below codes.

I feel I need to use a filter function but not sure where I need to place exactly.
Could you advise the solution?

models.py

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    title_in_English = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    titleslug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleslug
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["titleslug"]

class Conversationtext(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    english_conversations = models.CharField(max_length=255) #I want display only liked to the "particular title_in_English"
    english_pronunciation = models.CharField(max_length=255) #I want display only liked to the "particular title_in_English"
```

views.py

```
def blog_conversation(request, conversation):
    posts = Conversation.objects.filter(titleslug__contains=conversation).distinct()
    lists = Conversationtext.objects.distinct()
    context = {"conversation": conversation, "posts": posts, "lists": lists,}
    return render(request, "blog_conversation.html", context)
```

html

```
{% for i in posts.all %}
<p>{{i}}
<p>{{i.title_in_English}}
{% endfor %}

{{ lists }}
{% for i in lists %}
<p>English --> {{i.english_conversations}} -> I got all english_conversations queries
<p>English --> {{i.english_pronunciation}} -> I got all english_pronunciation.queries
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stay:

```
posts = Conversation.objects.filter(titleslug__contains=conversation)
```

```
{% for i in posts.all %}
    <p>{{i}}</p>
    <p>{{i.title_in_English}}</p>
    {{i.conversationext_set.all}}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope I understood you correctly

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! thank you very much.
Just 2 quick questions...
1. why did you remove the .distinct()
2. Is there any way to filter in views.py? I am just worrying if I put many data, for loop in HTML would take more time and makes the page slow loading... I am not sure tho

Comment: 1. `Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.` Django ORM returns non duplicate rows. 2. There is a method and there are more than one, you need to understand where the filtering set will come from, if it's hard from the code, then you can just use a filter, if you need to write processing from the querystring.
please, set answer as a useful.